# How to run a shell script on another server from kettle job at one server?

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Using Pentaho, I want to execute a shell script lying on another server in Kettle Job (.kjb) file using "Execute a Shell script" component. I was successful to run the script locally by giving script file name in that component. But I am not getting how to run a remote script.

Here is how my simple kjb looks like:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: locally working on server not working? what error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. By locally, I mean the kjb and shell file are on same machine... I want to run a shell script that is on different machine from where kjb resides.

Comment: The script will execute on same server as the Pentaho software runs. However, this script may launch a script on a distant server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is pretty straightforward using the **shell step** from a pentaho job:

1) on General tab check "insert script"

2) on Script tab now you are able to add this inline script:

```
ssh user@remotemachine 'ls -l'
```

this will execute ls -l on the remote server via ssh

make sure the ssh user is allowed to login with ssh keys, not asking for password.